# Go back to previous page after a delay

Tags: jquery, timeout, browser-history

I want to go to the previous page after a 2 second delay using jQuery. I thought maybe I could do it this way but I think 'm using this in the wrong context. Code doesn't do anything worthwhile.

```
function goBack() {
    $(this).delay(3000, function(){
      history.back();}
    return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The second argument to [`delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) is a `queueName`, not a function to run after the delay. Use `setTimeout` instead:

```
setTimeout(function(){history.back();}, 3000);
```

Comment: This came in handy for me today. However, and the strangest thing is that, when I changed 3000 to 5000, it failed on me.

Comment: Scratch that ^ I found my problem. I had other setTimeout functions with the same amount of time, duh. However, my comments may serve others who may think that it won't work, if/when they may also have been using the same amount of time for seperate setTimeout functions.

Answer (score 1):

**JS Code**

```
setTimeout('history.go(-1)', 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<button type="button" onclick="history.back();">Back</button>
```